# running word-counter example with hadoop and hbase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, bigdata

### word-counter example with hbase and hadoop

I am new to **hadoop** and **hbase**, i am going to implement a real example on a data set and understand the logic behind them.

I have already install hadoop and hbase on my system (ubuntu 17.04).

> hadoop-2.8.0
>
> hbase-1.3.1

is there any step-by-step tutorial for implementing word-counter example?
(word-counter example or any basic example exist)

Answer (score 0):

There is comprehensive tutorial provided in HBase reference guide:
http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#mapreduce.example

Note, HBase provides alternative mechanism called `Cascading` which is similar to Map-Reduce, but allow to write code in simplified way (it's described in ref. guide too).

Comment: thanks for help, can we just use web view and terminal to run the examples?? or we should writing code to do this??  @rumoku